# Why my python program returning different Output on every execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-manipulation

I have been doing a challenge to find a runner up score from a list

 **or** 
You can say I was trying to find the second largest from a list.

```py
array = '57 57 -57 57'

print(list(set(sorted(array.split(' '))))[-2])
```

But on every execution the program returning different Output.

- On first execution it returned `57`
- On Second execution it returned `-57`
- On *Third*, *Fourth*, *Fifth*, *Sixth*, *Seventh*  execution it returned `57`
- Again on Eigth execution it again returned `-57`

**Why it is behaving like this??**

Comment: A set is not an ordered data structure. I'm not really sure why you're using set at all - are you _supposed_ to be removing duplicates?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes to removing duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
array = '57 57 -57 57'

print(list(sorted(set(array.split(' '))))[-2])
```

'set' doesn't preserve the order, so first get the set value and then sort it.

Comment: I guess, `list` now becomes redundant, because `sorted` already returns a list.

Comment: @bereal It is no longer needed to wrap the entire thing in list.

Comment: @KunalTanwar that's exactly what I said.